# How convert this bash to powershell variable

Tags: bash, powershell

I need to convert the following bash variable to powershell variable

```
event='[ {"id": "'"$RANDOM"'", "eventType": "recordInserted", "subject": "myapp/vehicles/motorcycles", "eventTime": "'`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z`'", "data":{ "make": "Contoso", "model": "Monster"},"dataVersion": "1.0"} ]'
```

I found on how to replace

```
date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
```

by

```
$eventtimesend = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H%M"
```

but not sure how to replace or what is needed to be modified in order to inject the 2 variables $eventtimesend & $RANDOM to be compatible with powershell syntax.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use an expandable here-string, then either nest the variable expression in the string:

```
$eventtimesend = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H%M"

$eventJson = @"
[ {"id": "'"$RANDOM"'", "eventType": "recordInserted", "subject": "myapp/vehicles/motorcycles", "eventTime": "${eventtimesend}", "data":{ "make": "Contoso", "model": "Monster"},"dataVersion": "1.0"} ]
"@
```

... or, alternatively, make the `Get-Date` call in a subexpression `$(...)` directly in the string literal:

```
$eventJson = @"
[ {"id": "'"$RANDOM"'", "eventType": "recordInserted", "subject": "myapp/vehicles/motorcycles", "eventTime": "$(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H%M")", "data":{ "make": "Contoso", "model": "Monster"},"dataVersion": "1.0"} ]
"@
```

---

### What about `$RANDOM`?

PowerShell doesn't have any automatic variables like `$RANDOM`, so you'll want to replace it with a call to `Get-Random` instead:

```
$eventJson = @"
[ {"id": "$(Get-Random -Maximum ([int16]::MaxValue + 1))", "eventType": "recordInserted", "subject": "myapp/vehicles/motorcycles", "eventTime": "$(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H%M")", "data":{ "make": "Contoso", "model": "Monster"},"dataVersion": "1.0"} ]
"@
```

Comment: @eliassal You're most welcome! If my answer solves your problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)

Comment: Mathias, the "Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H%M" gives  "202302121723" but the bash function gives a date as follows  "2023-02-10T14:14:13+0100", the date generated by powershell is not accepted as date for an az client to create an object, it should be at least in the form "2023-02-10T14:14:13" at least